# I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on DateTime pass

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

```
if(dates == null)
{
    DateTime tempDate = WorldTimeAPI.instance.GetCurrentDateTime();
    print(tempDate);
    dates.SetDailyWeeklyDate(tempDate);
    SaveSystem.TaskDateSave(dates);
}
```

the error is on third line of the block. The print is printing the date, no issues there.

the `SetDailyWeeklyDates()` function is below:

```
public void SetDailyWeeklyDate(DateTime date)
{
    dailyTaskDate = date;
    weeklyTaskDate = date;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: "if(dates == null)" - you only get to the code if dates is null

Comment: `dates` is null when you get to that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"if(dates == null)" - you only get to the code if dates is null

You either want to change the code to "if(dates != null)" or create an instance of whatever class "dates" is before the third line.

Comment: Ahh I was thinking it was because of tempDate. thanks